# HTTP Status 500 Tomcat Unable to compile class for JSP Only a type can be imported

Tags: javascript, java, tomcat, servlets, web-applications

My web app using Tomcat 9.0.41 as a server is returning HTTP Status 500 with the following error messages. The problem appears to be directly correlated with my index.jsp, but I am not sure what the problem is. From reading through other stack overflow posts, it seems to be formatting error with the page imports but also maybe because I wrote Java code in the jsp file and that is not a good idea which is causing the error.

[image]

DatabaseHelper.java

```
package com.project.store;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DatabaseHelper {

    public Connection getConnection(){
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:// localhost:3306/" + "products", "root", "database101");
            return con;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException throwables) {
            throwables.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page import="javax.xml.crypto.Data" %>
<%@ page import="com.project.store.DatabaseHelper" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.Connection" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.Statement" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.ResultSet" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='styles.css'><link rel='stylesheet' href='//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
        <script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a904bba290.js' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div class='navbar'>
        <a class='logo'>Fashend</a>
        <a href='checkout.jsp'>Checkout</a>
    </div>
    <div id='products-section'>
        <%
            DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper();
            Connection connection = databaseHelper.getConnection();
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM products");
            while(rs.next()) {
                String id = rs.getString("id");
                String title = rs.getString("title");


                String image = rs.getString("image");
                int rate = rs.getInt("rate");
                String count = rs.getString("count");
                String details = "./details?name="+id;

        %>
        <a class="product" id="<%=id%>" href="<%=details%>">

            <img src="<%=image%>" id="<%=id%>">
            <h3 class="product-title" id="<%=id%>"><%=title%></h3>
            <%
                for (int i=0; i<rate; i++) {
            %>
                <i class='fa-solid fa-star'></i>
            <%
                }
            %>
            <%
                for (int i=0; i<5-rate; i++) {
            %>
                <i class='fa-regular fa-star'></i>
            <%
                }
            %>
            <span class="review-count"><%=count%>&nbsp;&nbsp;reviews</span>

        </a>

        <% } connection.close();%>
    </div>
    <jsp:include page="/latestProducts.jsp"/>
</body>
</html>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.project.store</groupId>
  <artifactId>pa_3</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>pa_3 Maven Webapp</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.28</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>pa_3</finalName>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: There seem to be no dependency in your pom.xml which might contain the `DatabaseHelper` class, so perhaps you need to create a maven project for your java stuff

Comment: What would the dependency look like inside of the pom.xml? I wasn't aware that was needed to be created for the java class and assumed importing it was enough for index.jsp.

Comment: you don't need to add anything to your pom - can you make sure your classes are compiled to your `/WEB-INF/classes` folder?  Sometimes the IDE will not do it for you automatically (if your project is not setup correctly) so you have to do it manually.

Comment: When I build the project with maven, it creates a target folder and under pa_3/WEB-INF/classes there is no files. Is this what is meant by needing the classes to be compiled to this folder? I am not doing it correctly with Visual Studio Code and [reference image here](https://imgur.com/a/5xvHIFK)